# Intellij has no plugins downloaded

Tags: plugins, intellij-plugin

I installed InteliJ Community today, and I have no plugins downloaded. Also the "create new project button does not work. When i click the "plugins" section in settings it shows nothing. I tried reinstalling Intelij, but nothing.

What should I do?

Comment: What if you click "browse repositories" ? And did you need to set up a web proxy if you are sitting behind one?

Comment: Solved! I reinstalled the latest version from terminal.